# Plot to image object

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I can save a single plot with `imshow()`, since it returns an image object, like this:

```
image = plt.imshow(list, interpolation=None)
```

Later I want to create an animation of many of those images, that I save in a list and render it as a video. (If this approach is stupid, please let me know, I fear I am doing something wrong.)

```
anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=15, blit=True)
```

But I have no idea how I can do the same with a figure of two subplots. Shouldn't there also be a function that returns me an image object?

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(list, interpolation=None)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.imshow(list, interpolation=None)

plt.show()
```

Instead of showing the plot, I want to save it as an image object.
My goal is to create an animation (of many plots) and render it as a video. Maybe my approach is wrong. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I want to create an animation of many plots and render it as a video. Maybe my approach is wrong in the first place.

Comment: How I do it, is the big question. For single imshow plots I can save all images in a list and then render the video with matplotlib animation.

Comment: I save all images in a list of images and then do the animation:
`anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=15, blit=True)`

I am new to this topic and I fear I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. It is a really different question now.

Comment: I created a new question that is clearer to understand. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can save it to an *"in-memory"* buffer like this:

```
# Save PNG to memory buffer as BytesIO
from io import BytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()

plt.savefig(buffer,format='png')
PNG = buffer.getvalue()
```

If you mean you want a PIL/Pillow Image from that:

```
reloadedPILImage = Image.open(buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an adaption of [this example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) to work with two lists of data.
Note that when the images don't all have the same range of data, the range will be taken from the first element drawn. A workaround is to explicitly set vmin and vmax to the global minimum and maximum.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 5, 30), np.linspace(0, 5, 10))
list1 = [np.sin(x + i * 0.10) * np.cos(y + i * 0.01) for i in range(50)]
list2 = [np.cos(x + i * 0.01) * np.sin(y + i * 0.10) for i in range(50)]
list1[0] = np.zeros_like(list1[0])  # test what happens when the first element has only one color

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

vmin1 = min([l.min() for l in list1 ])
vmin2 = min([l.min() for l in list2 ])
vmax1 = max([l.max() for l in list1 ])
vmax2 = max([l.max() for l in list2 ])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
im1 = ax1.imshow(list1[0], interpolation=None, animated=True, vmin=vmin1, vmax=vmax1)
im2 = ax2.imshow(list2[0], interpolation=None, animated=True, cmap='inferno', vmin=vmin2, vmax=vmax2)

def updatefig(i):
    im1.set_array(list1[i])
    im2.set_array(list2[i])
    return im1, im2,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=len(list1), interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It just renders the first element of my list, because of `im1 = ax1.imshow(list1[0], interpolation=None, animated=True)`

Comment: Only the first element of the lists is plottet over and over again. Which makes sense, since im1 and im2 are defined as a plot of the 0th element.

Comment: The problem is here: `im1 = ax1.imshow(list1[0], interpolation=None, animated=True)` at `list1[0]`. I tried a lot, but I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: It is looping through updatefig just fine. But the plots are always plotted with the first list item. In your example-link, there is a function used: `im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)`. That's what I probably also need.

Comment: I am not running Python 2. Why do you think that?

Comment: I succeeded, but have a strange issue. In case you are still interested, I opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917379/funcanimation-issue
Again, thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Like a charm. Perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: You might consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer

Comment: I found out something else. It was not the type or shape of `list[0]`. Shape and type are identical to the following list elements. The first one is a numpy array of zeros. The following list elements contain random numbers.
If `list[0]` contains only zeros, the animation will only show zeros. If `list[0]` contains only 100s, the animation will only show 100s. If list[0] contains only 0s and 1s, the animation will only show 0s and 1s. Somehow with `im1 = ax1.imshow(list1[0], interpolation=None, animated=True)` the plot is initialized and does not take any other value.

Comment: Well, I didn't expect this as an issue. Sorry for your time. But thank you very much. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.savefig('someimgname.jpg')
```

This will do the trick. But remember after you do this - open this with `Image.Open()` and this will work.

```
im  = Image.open('someimgname.jpg')
im.show() # or do whatever you want to do with this image object
```

Example code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(list, interpolation=None)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.imshow(list, interpolation=None)
plt.savefig('someimgname.jpg')
im = Image.open("someimgname.jpg")  # desired image object
im.show()
plt.show()
```

References:

1. [Pillow Reference](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)
2. [Matplotlib Reference](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=save#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Ok for the second part of the answer, while I checked the doc for `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(*args, **kwargs)` it said.

The first argument `fname` is `A path, or a Python file-like object, or possibly some backend-dependent object such as`.

In python file like object is `StringIO` objects.

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='jpg')
buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)
```

From python documentation, it made even more sense:-

> In-memory streams: It is also possible to use a str or bytes-like
>   object as a file for both reading and writing. For strings StringIO
>   can be used like a file opened in text mode. BytesIO can be used like
>   a file opened in binary mode. Both provide full read-write
>   capabilities with random access.

Example code: (**In memory**)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import io

list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(list, interpolation=None)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.imshow(list, interpolation=None)
plt.show()
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='jpg')
buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)
im.show()
```

Reference:
3. [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: I don't want it as a file, I need an image object, to save it in a list.

Comment: @Dusty.: Check the example

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't help me. I need to do this wih a lot of plots and I cannot save them as a file before. Shouldn't there be an easy way? Isn't that a basic need?

Comment: @Dusty.: Let me check the doc once.

Comment: What I don't understand: If I do it with one imshow() plot, it is easily done. Shouldn't it be also possible with a plot of subplots?

I need these images for an animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
plt.savefig('name.png')
```

Comment: I don't want it as a file, I need an image object, to save it in a list.