# How to save bmp format using matplotlib without saving to png image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Here is the code that works fine:

```
TempImage = "image.png"
SaveImage = "image.bmp"
plt.savefig(TempImage, format = "png")
img = Image.open(TempImage)
img.save(SaveImage)
os.remove(TempImage)
```

I was looking for an option to save matplotlib plot to image but needed bmp format. Since there was no solution so I found this. But it creates extra png file tat I have to delete since it is no use to me and may acquire space on disk.

So I was looking for a solution that will avoid saving the png file and directly convert the plot to bmp file format.

Please let me know what I can do to achieve it.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60901238/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell No I have not checked it. But it seems to work for me. I will try this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid going via PNG, you could go via a raw RGBA buffer.  This has the advantage of being slightly faster than going into/out of a PNG file.

It's slightly more involved, but the following works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

def fig_to_image(figure: plt.Figure, *, dpi=None, **kwds) -> Image:
    if dpi is None:
        dpi = figure.dpi
    dims = tuple(int(n * dpi) for n in figure.get_size_inches())
    buf = BytesIO()
    figure.savefig(buf, format='RGBA', dpi=dpi, **kwds)
    return Image.frombuffer('RGBA', dims, buf.getbuffer())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig_to_image(fig).save('figure.bmp')
```

I should note that because BMP files aren't compressed the resulting files are enormous.  So even if you did produce intermediate PNGs it would be unlikely to affect disk usage significantly.  For example, the above produces a 1,228,854 byte BMP and a 7,927 byte PNG, so the PNG takes 0.6% of the storage space.